# Como se formam os superlativos absolutos, sintético e analítico, de magra?

Tags: superlativos

Tenho o adjetivo `magro`.

O que seria coloca-lo em grau superlativo absoluto sintético e analítico?

Em que casos eu elevaria o grau de um adjetivo?

Answer (score 3):

Para o adjetivo *magra*, a forma no grau superlativo absoluto analítico é *muito magra* e no grau superlativo absoluto sintético é *magríssima*. Graus diferentes do normal são usados para dar ênfase ao fato de que o sujeito é, neste caso mais magro que a média, por uma grande margem.

Answer (score 1):

Os graus de um adjetivo são formas nas quais ele pode ser flexionado para estabelecer uma ideia correlata; no português, existem três graus para um adjetivo (embora alguns poucos adjetivos possam não ter os três graus):

- grau positivo: é a forma comum do adjetivo, que serve para expressá-lo de forma absoluta: *um cavalheiro **magro**.*
- grau comparativo: é uma forma usada para estabelecer uma comparação entre dois entes baseados na qualidade que o adjetivo denota. No latim, era uma única palavra, mas no português se usa a locução *mais* + «grau positivo»: *Alice é **mais magra** que Beth.*
- grau superlativo: originalmente era usada para marcar um grau de excelência com relação à qualidade que o adjetivo denota, mas essa forma foi substituída pela locução *o/a mais «grau positivo»*. Atualmente só é utilizada para enfatizar uma qualidade.

O superlativo tem duas formas, uma dita *analítica* e a outra *sintética*. A forma analítica usa a locução *muito* + «grau positivo»: *rapaz **muito magro***. A forma sintética deriva do antigo superlativo latino e se forma com um sufixo; no caso de magro é *-érrimo*: *Ana está **magérrima**.*